# SwiftUI: How to implement horizontal automatic scrolling scrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I found this functionality: [Look](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/VJG3GYU7f6c) of an auto-scrolling horizontal scrollview and would now like to include it in my app. Does anyone know how something like this might work or where I can start? I appreciate help. Best regards

Comment: @PtitXav there is no ability to set offset of ScrollView content. So your comment is useless

Comment: You may try using a LazyHStack from a buttons array on which you remove first element with animation , and  add it to the end .